# Decoding bit to find string - Requesting Huffman technique

Tags: c#, .net, bit, decoding, huffman-code

I am trying to build a decoder for example

```
a           100100
b           100101
c           110001
d           100000
[newline]   111111
p           111110
q           000001
```

The encode bits:

```
111110000001100100111111100101110001111110
```

This should give

```
pqa
bcp
```

The code I tried:

```
static string decode(string[] codes, string encoded) {
            string finalString = string.Empty;
            string temp = string.Empty;
            System.Collections.Hashtable hashtable = new System.Collections.Hashtable();

            for (int i = 0; i < codes.Length; i++)
            {
                if (codes[i].Split()[0].Contains("new"))
                {
                    var newLine = Environment.NewLine;
                    hashtable.Add(codes[i].Split()[1], newLine);
                    continue;
                }
                hashtable.Add(codes[i].Split()[1], codes[i].Split()[0]);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i <= encoded.Length; i++)
            {
                if (codes.Length!=finalString.Length)
                {
                    temp = temp + encoded[i];
                    if (hashtable[temp] != null)
                    {
                        finalString = finalString + hashtable[temp].ToString();
                        encoded = encoded.Remove(0, temp.Length);
                        temp = string.Empty;
                        i = -1;
                    }
                }
            }
            return finalString;

    }
```

But it seems to fail for most of the test case. Can anyone point out the mistake I did? And also anyway to improve the performance of the above code?

Also is there any way to decode faster? I mean the encoded string can be of length 7000 and codes can be up to 100. Its taking much time for execution of these. I studied about Hoffman decoding . can that be used here to fasten up?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I run your code, by supplying the parameters as follows:

```
string[] str = new string[] { "a 100100","b 100101","c 110001","d 100000","[newline] 111111","p 111110","q 000001" };
string encoded = @"111110000001100100111111100101110001111110";
string res = decode(str, encoded);
```

The result is `"pqa\r\nbc"`. That's not far from the desired result, it just misses the last character.

You can fix that by simplifying the second `for` loop to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < encoded.Length; i++)
{
    temp = temp + encoded[i];
    if (hashtable[temp] != null)
    {
        finalString = finalString + hashtable[temp].ToString();
        encoded = encoded.Remove(0, temp.Length);
        temp = string.Empty;
        i = -1;
    }
}
```

I removed the `if` because I don't understand it :P and notice the `i < encoded.Length` instead of `i <= encoded.Length`, which would then otherwise cause an exception.

Some notes on your implementation:

- Instead of `Hashtable` you could use a `Dictionary<string, string>`, and `dictionary.TryGetValue(...)` to test whether it contains a certain string
- If the "codes" always have the same length, you can simplify your code not having to iterate over every single character separately
- Save the result of `codes[i].Split()` into a variable, instead of repeating it multiple times

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it.  Note that I changed the signature of `decode()` to receive a string instead of a string array:

```
static string decode(string codes, string encoded)
```

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string codes = "a 100100 b 100101 c 110001 d 100000 [newline] 111111 p 111110 q 000001";
    string encoded = "111110000001100100111111100101110001111110";

    Console.WriteLine("");
    try
    {
        string decoded = decode(codes, encoded);

        Console.WriteLine("codes:");
        Console.WriteLine(codes);
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("encoded: ");
        Console.WriteLine(encoded);
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("decoded: ");
        Console.WriteLine(decoded);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Decoding Failed.");
        Console.WriteLine("Reason: " + ex.Message);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.Write("Press [Enter] to exit...");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static string decode(string codes, string encoded)
{
    StringBuilder decoded = new StringBuilder();

    List<Tuple<string, string>> codePairs = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
    string[] codeValues = codes.Trim().Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (codeValues.Length % 2 != 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("Invalid number of code pairs!");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < codeValues.Length - 1; i = i + 2)
    {
        if (codeValues[i].ToLower() == "[newline]")
        {
            codePairs.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(Environment.NewLine, codeValues[i + 1]));
        }
        else
        {
            codePairs.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(codeValues[i], codeValues[i + 1]));
        }
    }

    Boolean matchFound;
    while(encoded.Length > 0)
    {
        matchFound = false;
        foreach(Tuple<string, string> codePair in codePairs)
        {
            if (encoded.StartsWith(codePair.Item2))
            {
                encoded = encoded.Remove(0, codePair.Item2.Length);
                decoded.Append(codePair.Item1);
                matchFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!matchFound)
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid encoded string!  No matching code found.");
        }
    }

    return decoded.ToString();
}
```

Which produced the following output:

```
codes:
a 100100 b 100101 c 110001 d 100000 [newline] 111111 p 111110 q 000001

encoded:
111110000001100100111111100101110001111110

decoded:
pqa
bcp

Press [Enter] to exit...
```

Comment: is there any way to decode faster? i mean the encoded string can be of length 7000 and codes can be upto 100. its taking much time for execution of these. I studied about hoffman decoding . can that be used here to fasten up?

Comment: Can you put the length 7000 sample encoded string and up to 100 codes on PasteBin maybe so I can test speeds?

Comment: Any progress?  I have some ideas, but would love that longer sample data to test against.

Comment: i am not able to generate input of those big datas :(